# Correct way to pass vector of huge const objects

Tags: c++

I want to pass to function a vector of huge objects that cannot be changed inside the function. Obviously, I want to avoid copying these objects. Also, I do not want to use pointers. I tried to use reference_wrapper but it gives errors.

The function will also often be called with a brace-enclosed list of such objects (when they are constructed on-the-fly).

MWE with pointers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct HugeObject {
    int value = 42;
    // large chuck of data inside
};

HugeObject operator*(const HugeObject &a, const HugeObject &b) {
    return {a.value * b.value};
}

HugeObject op2(const HugeObject &a, const HugeObject &b) {
    HugeObject ret_obj;
    // calculate return object based on a and b
    return ret_obj;
}

HugeObject f(const HugeObject &a, const HugeObject &b, const HugeObject &c) {
    HugeObject ret_obj;
    // calculate return object based on a, b, and c
    return ret_obj;
}

double do_some_calculation(const vector<HugeObject *> &objects) {
    double ret_val = 0.0;
    // do some calculation on objects
    return ret_val;
}

int main() {
    vector<HugeObject> a{{33}, {666}, {32}, {22}, {735}, {0}, {-123}};
    vector<HugeObject *> subset_1{&a[0], &a[3], &a[4]};
    vector<HugeObject *> subset_2{&a[2], &a[4]};

    cout << do_some_calculation(subset_1) << endl;
    cout << do_some_calculation(subset_2) << endl;
    cout << do_some_calculation({&a[0], &a[1]}) << endl;

    // I would like also to call do_some_calculation() on list constructed in place, something like this:
    cout << do_some_calculation({a[0], a[1] * a[2], op2(a[0], a[4]), f(a[0], a[1], a[2])}) << endl; // obviously, error

    HugeObject b = a[1] * a[2],
            c = op2(a[0], a[4]),
            d = f(a[0], a[1], a[2]);
    cout << do_some_calculation({&a[0], &b, &c, &d}) << endl; // compiles but looks ugly

    return 0;
}
```

In the last call, the objects constructed by operations (or functions) are used once only, so I don't care about them - but I want `a[0]` to still stay unchanged. Of course, I can name each of `a[1] * a[2]`, `op2(a[0], a[4])`, `f(a[0], a[1], a[2])` as a variable (end of the source code) and then use references to them in the call, but it makes code looking much uglier.

Comment: This question seems to be more generic and not tied to a specific C++ standard version, so I changed the tag.

Comment: Yes, perhaps. I just use C++17 and perhaps solutions in this version could be easier.

Comment: As for your problem, if you pass the vector by reference there's no copying of the vector or its contents.

Comment: Why not simply `double do_some_calculation(const vector<HugeObject> &objects) {` ? No copy will happen.

Comment: I will use `do_some_calculation()` on different subsets of the big set of `HugeObject`s hence I want the function to accept a vector of references. I will update the question.

Comment: Please fix "const obejcts" in the title.

Comment: Question (including title) updated

Comment: in your code you never pass a vector of huge objects anywhere. Either it is pass by reference or you pass a vector of pointers. Please take some time to reconsider what is the actual problem you are trying to solve. Currently it is not clear from the question

Answer (score 1):

You are already passing the vector as const reference, so it is not really clear why you want to wrap the elements also.

For the second call, I would rather refactor the algorithm into:

```
template <typename IT>
double do_some_calculation_with_multiplied_elements(IT begin, IT end, IT mult_begin, IT mult_end) {
    double ret_val = 0.0;
    // multiply mult_begin up to mult_end and use the result
    return ret_val;
}
```

Such that this:

```
cout << do_some_calculation({a[0], a[1] * a[2]}) << endl;
```

would become:

```
cout << do_some_calculation_with_multiplied_elements(a.begin(),a.begin()+1, a.begin()+2, a.end()) << endl;
```

Comment: Perhaps, my MWE was not explanatory enough. Sorry for that. 1) I will construct vectors of references to HugeObject's because I will need to run do_some_calculation() on different subsets of the objects and I don't want to mutliply entities :) 2) There are more different operations on HugeObjects I will use - all arithmetic, and other functions. I will re-write the question.

Comment: @YauhenYakimenka sorry but after the edit I understand even less what problem you are trying to solve. You know have pointers in the vectors and pointers are not heavy objects. For the third call `do_some_calculation({&a[0], &a[1]})` no single `HugeObject` is copied (and also none for the others)

Comment: @YauhenYakimenka and for your last edit: your last call trying to call the function with a vector of `HugeObject`s, that wont work, as you changed it to work on vectors of pointers

Comment: I actually would like to _avoid_ pointers - the example is just what I want to achieve and it works with pointers. But pointers are bad as I am afraid to mess up with them somewhere in the code.

Comment: As to the last edit, this is just to show approximately how I would like to call the function. Obviously, it doesn't work like it is now.

Comment: @YauhenYakimenka why do you think pointers are bad? It would be bad if your `a` vector, the one that owns the objects, would store pointers, but there is nothing bad about non-owning pointers. A rule of thumb is "Dont use raw owning pointers. Never." and false simplification made "Dont use raw pointers" out of it, but thats non-sense. if you need to refer to an object without participating in ownership then raw pointers are fine (especially when you just pass them to a function and that function does not store those pointers)

Comment: @YauhenYakimenka anyhow, as suggested in the answer, I would not pass the container but iterators, then the whole problem of passing around `HugeObject`s is gone

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Now I think that perhaps `shared_ptr` might be a bit safer option than just pointers?..